# Get value from another table Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables like -

Table A -

| Seller | Value | Crawl_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mat | 2 | 28-Aril-2023 |
| Harry | 32 | 28-Aril-2023 |
| cat | 0 | 28-Aril-2023 |
| Jon |  | 28-Aril-2023 |
| Sohan | 121 | 28-Aril-2023 |
| Ray | 3223 | 28-Aril-2023 |
| Mat | 2 | 26-Aril-2023 |
| Harry | 32 | 26-Aril-2023 |
| cat | 0 | 26-Aril-2023 |
| Jon |  | 26-Aril-2023 |
| Sohan | 121 | 26-Aril-2023 |
| Ray | 3223 | 26-Aril-2023 |

Table B-

| Seller |
| --- |
| Mat |
| Harry |
| cat |
| Jon |
| Om |

My expected output would be, to create a new column for table B called "check" and assign True or 1 if the same seller is in A and if its value is greater than 0 and it should be based on the latest crawl date.

Table B -

| Seller | Check |
| --- | --- |
| Mat | True |
| Harry | True |
| cat | False |
| Jon | False |
| Om | False |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED REQUIREMENTS**

```
Check = 
VAR x = SELECTCOLUMNS( TOPN(1, FILTER('Table A', 'Table A'[Seller] = 'Table B'[Seller]), CALCULATE(MAX('Table A'[Crawl_date])), DESC) ,"@y", 'Table A'[Value])
RETURN IF(x > 0 , TRUE(), FALSE())
```

Add a calculated column as follows:

```
Check = 
VAR x = LOOKUPVALUE('Table A'[Value], 'Table A'[Seller], 'Table B'[Seller])
RETURN IF(x > 0 , TRUE(), FALSE())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi David ,
I am getting the below error msg.
A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

Comment: Table A has multiple value-based on the crawl date. 
I need to get the value on the latest crawl date. 
I have updated Table A.

Comment: Please can you make sure to include all the relevant info next time.

Comment: Sure I will take care of it.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Update added for you

Comment: Sorry, Still getting the same issue

Comment: Then something else is happening and you haven't supplied all the information. I have tested it and it works fine with your sample data.

Comment: I have one question for you can u please review it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370897/apply-dual-filter-using-one-slicer