# Apply dual filter using one slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a very big table loaded in Power BI. Below is the sample one

| ID | date | qtr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/25/2019 | 2020 Q3 |
| 2 | 5/9/2019 | 2020 Q3 |
| 3 | 4/29/2021 | 2022 Q2 |
| 4 | 3/11/2021 | 2021 Q1 |
| 5 | 10/25/2021 | 2022 Q2 |
| 6 | 9/22/2021 | 2022 Q1 |
| 7 | 4/11/2022 | 2023 Q1 |
| 8 | 5/9/2019 | 2020 Q3 |
| 9 | 4/5/2023 | 2024 Q2 |
| 10 | 3/7/2023 | 2020 Q3 |

I have a similar table in Power BI and implemented a slicer of "exp_qtr".

If I am selecting any "qtr" from the slicer option then along with "qtr" filter, all date before that should select.

Eg - If I am selecting 2020 Q3 and then select "qtr" also on "date" select dates which are less than the Q3 2020 quarter ( less than July 2020)  my expected output of the table is -

| ID | date | qtr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/25/2019 | 2020 Q3 |
| 2 | 5/9/2019 | 2020 Q3 |
| 8 | 5/9/2019 | 2020 Q3 |

Note - Not included in the last row because its date is greater than July 2020. Here, I am using the slicer option( qtr). Action_date is in date format and  "qtr" is in string.

Comment: what will be the output when "2021 Q1" is selected?

Comment: The date should be less than that qtr. It should be less than  1 Jan 2021.

Comment: For the same selected Quarter?

Comment: Whatever quarter we are selecting the date column should be less than that quarter.
Like for Q1 2020 the date should be less than that quarter. This means the date column should display only up to Dec 2019.

Comment: Then you probably need to remove "&& selected_exp_qtr == exp_qtr" this part from the below Measure I have written in my answer. But you can play with the code.

Comment: Can you please update the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253893/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-harry).

Comment: I am unable to create the table using existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a separate table for "exp_qtr" slicer, then it's fine. Otherwise, create a new table "quarter_slicer" in the power query editor with the following code-

```
let
    Source = your_table_name,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"exp_qtr"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

Now create a measure as below-

```
show_hide_row = 

var selected_exp_qtr = SELECTEDVALUE(quarter_slicer[exp_qtr])
var year_ = LEFT(selected_exp_qtr,4)
var quarter_ = RIGHT(selected_exp_qtr,1)
var month_ = if(quarter_ = "1", 1, if(quarter_ = "2", 4, if(quarter_ = "3", 7, if(quarter_ = "4", 10 ))))

return 
if(
    (
        MIN(your_table_name[Action_date]) <= DATE(year_,month_,1)-1
    )
        || ISBLANK(selected_exp_qtr),
    1,
    0
)
```

Now add the new Measure in the filter property of your table visual as shown below-

[image]

And here is the output when you select a Quarter in the slicer-

[image]